# How can I escape the ajaxStart event

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

### The problem:

A loading message will appear when ajax request start:

```
$('#container').ajaxStart(function(){ showFlashMessage(); })
```

And will disappear after ajax request stops:

```
$('#container').ajaxStart(function(){ $('#flashMessage').remove(); })
```

Now I want to escape(ignore) the ajaxStart event after 3 ajax requests sent.

### What I tried:

I tried following codes, but neither works:(

```
$('#container').ajaxStart(function(){})
```

or

```
$('#container').ajaxStop(function(){ $('#flashMessage').remove(); })
```

### Question

How can I escape (ignore) the ajaxStart event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a global counter variable.

```
var count = 0;
$('#container').ajaxStart(function(){
    if(count > 2) return false;
    showFlashMessage();
    count++;
});
```